# Move window scroll

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I have a fixed `45px` height bar that's visible once you go pass a certain point.

The issue is that I also have inter-page links (e.g. comments IDs), so whenever I link to a comment I can't view it entirely because the fixed bar stays on top of it.

I have this code:

```
    if(window.location.hash) {

    }
```

in which I'd like to include the code to move the scroll bar up with `45px` from its current position, so the fixed bar doesn't overlay.

I've tried with `$(window).scrollTop();`, but it doesn't move anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top - 45});
```

Comment: `$(window.location.hash)` is XSS vulnerability in jQuery < 1.6.1 http://ma.la/jquery_xss/

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work, though. It moves the page to a complete other position, but not with -45px from here the # is.